# eclipse hadoop connection refused

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running WordCount example of mapreduce on hadoop on my local.
When I run it with the command:

```
hadoop jar MRTest.jar example.WordCount /gutenberg /out333
```

It works.

in the command

```
MRTest.jar is the jar package which exported from my eclipse.
/gutenberg is the input path on my hdfs.
/out333 is the output path on my hdfs.
```

but when I run it on eclipse with arguments :

```
hdfs://localhost:9000/gutenberg hdfs://localhost:9000/output6
```

it throws the following exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From SWD-LIUQIN00-D1/172.26.35.141 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at $Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at $Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:651)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1679)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1106)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1397)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
at example.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:81)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:547)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:642)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2600(Client.java:314)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1399)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1318)
... 28 more
```

Here is some config on my local:

slaves:

```
hadoop-slave141
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       hadoop-slave141 localhost
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/data/hadoop/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/data/hadoop/dfs/hadoop2/name</value>
    <description>Path on the local filesystem where the NameNode stores the namespace and transactions logs persistently.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/data/hadoop/dfs/hadoop2/data</value>
    <description>Comma separated list of paths on the local filesystem of a DataNode where it should store its blocks.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
  <value>hadoop-master:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
  <value>hadoop-master:19888</value>
</property>
<property> 
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name> //JobTracker的主机（或者IP）和端口。
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-master:8031</value>
        <description>host is the hostname of the resource manager and    port is the port on which the NodeManagers contact the Resource Manager.          </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-master:8030</value>
        <description>host is the hostname of the resourcemanager and port is the port    on which the Applications in the cluster talk to the Resource Manager.          </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
        <description>In case you do not want to use the default scheduler</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0:8032</value>
    <description>the host is the hostname of the ResourceManager and the port is the port on    which the clients can talk to the Resource Manager. </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/nodemanager/local</value>
        <description>the local directories used by the nodemanager</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0:8034</value>
        <description>the nodemanagers bind to this port</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
        <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/nodemanager/remote</value>
    <description>directory on hdfs where the application logs are moved to </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
        <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/nodemanager/logs</value>
        <description>the directories used by Nodemanagers as log directories</description>
    </property>
    <!-- Use mapreduce_shuffle instead of mapreduce.suffle (YARN-1229)-->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop fs -ls /  :

```
14/04/22 10:24:30 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 9 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup    1195054 2014-04-18 08:27 /gutenberg
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-21 20:38 /out222
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-22 09:55 /out333
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-18 08:45 /output
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-18 11:23 /output2
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-18 11:28 /output3
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-18 13:38 /output3jps
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-21 17:48 /outt
drwx------   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-04-18 08:44 /tmp
```

jps:

```
11149 Jps
7762 ResourceManager
8074 NodeManager
6901 NameNode
7204 DataNode
7565 SecondaryNameNode
```

I tested both eclipse helios and also kelper.

hadoop version is 2.2.0.

I am also wondering what is the diff between running with the command line and in eclipse.

I use hadoop user which is the user of my hadoop from start to end.
And Eclipse is also launched by hadoop user.

Somebody please help me, I 've stucked on this for 3 days.

Comment: Seems I found out the reason.

The arguments I use should be the path on my local not path on HDFS

Change 

    hdfs://localhost:9000/gutenberg hdfs://localhost:9000/output6

into

    /data/workspace/gutenberg /tmp/output6

And the issue can be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the HDFS path as argument.
Try to change the value of `fs.defalutFS` in "core-site.xml" to **localhost**:

```xml
    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
```

And then restart the Hadoop.